# What is the best way to use ui-router to load directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have configred my ui-routes as follows:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<home>',
        resolve: {
            authorize: ['authorization',
                function(authorization) {
                    return authorization.authorize();
                }
            ]
        }
    })

.state('manage', {
    url: 'manage',
    abstract: true,
    template:'<div ui-view></div>',
    resolve: {
        authorize: ['authorization',
            function(authorization) {
                return authorization.authorize();
            }
        ]
    }
})

.state('manage.map', {
    parent: 'manage',
    url: '/map',
    template: '<dummy>',
    resolve: {
        authorize: ['authorization',
            function(authorization) {
                return authorization.authorize();
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

in my index. html, I have a ui-view :

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

The problem i am having is that when i type : /manage/map (or any other child route) in the browser the view is not loaded, the state is considered invalid.

The only way for it to work loading 'home' first and then with a button (ui-sref) accessing the 'manage.map' state.

In fact, when I have $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); 'manage.map' is always considered invalid, and I am always redirected to '/' even when i access it with ui-sref.

So I am not sure what i am doing wrong or what is the best way to use ui-router with directives ..

Comment: Are you sure that's it's not your authorize resolve that cause some trouble ?

Comment: I just removed authorize from all my routes and i still have the same problem, i think it has to do with ui-view.. but i'm not sure how

Comment: try remove the abstract:true. I have the same config than you without that abstract. Furhtermore are you loading your state on a normal config phase or do you have a dynamic/asynchronous part with it ? And rename your view manage to home.manage and manage.map to home.manage.map

Comment: even after removing abstract:true i still have the same problem, the current state i get is empty {"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true} i am using a normal config phase

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the missing '/' from the definition of the parent state ..

```
.state('manage', {
    url: '/manage',
    abstract: true,
    template:'<div ui-view></div>',
    resolve: {
        authorize: ['authorization',
            function(authorization) {
                return authorization.authorize();
            }
        ]
    }
})
```